# Divide the numerator and denominator by the highest power of x in the denominator to find the limit.

Tags: calculus

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{5 \sqrt{x} + x^{-1}}{4x+3}
$$

Im not sure how to answer this problem by dividing.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in the topic title? What did you end up with?

Answer (score 1):

MadinaW,

$$\frac{5}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}, \space \frac{1}{x^2}, \space \frac{3}{x} \to 0, \space x\to\infty$$

So therefore 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{5}{\sqrt
x}+\frac{1}{x^2}} {4+\frac{3}{x}} = \frac{0 + 0}{4 + 0} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{5\sqrt x+x^{-1}}{4x+3}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{5/\sqrt
x+1/x^2}{4+3/x}$$

Comment: How would I then solve for the answer. The answer is 0.

Comment: @MadinaW, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{x^n}=0$$ for $n>0$

Comment: Im still a little confused because in my problem there are still X in the numerator and denominator

Comment: @MadinaW, set $\sqrt x=\frac1h\implies  h\to0$ and $x=\frac1{h^2},x^2=\frac1{h^4}$